# How to use focus and blur on dynamic inserted elements?

Tags: jquery

I have function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input.myclass").focus(function() {
        // something
    }).blur(function() {
        // something
    });

}
```

and html:

```
<div class="usil">
    <div class="editable">
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="myclass" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

On load page jquery on "myclass" elements work fine but other script add dynamically "usil" class divs and on this divs jquery dont work. How to do it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
    $(document).on('focus',"input.myclass", function() {
        // something
    }).on('blur',"input.myclass", function() {
        // something
    });
```

or

```
$(document).on({
    'focus': function () {
        // something
    },
    'blur': function () {
        // something
    }
}, 'input.myclass');
```

http://api.jquery.com/on

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: +1 Nicely simple and straight

Comment: It should be noted that use of `document` is not generally a good idea if it can be avoided.  For performance reasons, you want to use the closest common static ancestor element.

Comment: Yes, that's worth noting -- although I wasn't going to go into that just now, since it was clearly a new concept to OP, and the difference in typical use is insignificant.

Answer (score -1):

That code could help:

```
$('input').live('focus', function() {
    $('label span').text('focus');
}).live('blur', function() {
    $('label span').text('blur');
});
```

Usage example:
http://jsfiddle.net/CPQ37/

Comment: .live was discontinued since v1.9: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354040/jquery-1-9-live-is-not-a-function